# Why can't I use iMessages using cellular data any more on my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, messages

Why can't I use iMessages using cellular data any more on my iPhone? I can use it with wifi, but when I turn on cellular, the message keeps popping out that my cellular data needs to be turned on (which it is!), or wifi in order for iMessages to work.

Comment: Have you checked your cellular settings in Settings > Cellular to allow Messages to use cellular data?

Comment: Messages are not listed there for me.